# SQL Server query issue based on the column value populate the result in other column. We can add date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

In the attached scenario, one of the column "result" is showing fail in one of the row and remaining all scenarios showing it as pass. In this case, I need to populate in "status" column i need to show it as fail. if user passes in all subjects then only in status column against all subjects we need to show it as PASS.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, are you looking to do so using an UPDATE or a SELECT? Also, please do not post data as images, instead post them as formatted text or DDL and DML to let others test it and brings a proper answer.

Comment: i want to write a select statement

Comment: select sno, subject, case when result = fail then status =fail from tbl1 if any result is showing different values like fail, pass then for that respective student we need to show it as fail in status inspite of he passed in all the remaining subjects else if he passes in all the subjects and in status column all the records are pass then we need populate PASS

Comment: Alright, so what did you try to solve your issue? @Nandkishor Gat

Comment: i have tried string agg for the student number and got the required results by doing group by sno, subject.   for this sno the string agg will return (pass, fail) so as it is pass, fail....i can make the status as fail. but my real challenge is i have 100+ columns and 5 billion records. so i don't think the solution which i worked is correct

Comment: (select AB.sno,string_agg(test,',') as Agg,
case when  string_agg(test,',') = 'PASS' then 'PASS' 
when string_agg(test,',') in ('cancelled,pass') then 'pass' 
when string_agg(test,',') in ('pass,Cancelled') then 'pass' 
 else 'fail' end as Samplestatus,
from
(select  distinct sno,Result as test, updateddate as date1 
 from
(select  a.sno,a.subj as resno,subjectdetails,
a.date1, a.date11,

Comment: MAX(date1) OVER (ORDER BY sno,status ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS updateddate,
Modified,

status1 as statusdescription,Result as ResultStatus,TestStatus

from  a 
join  b on
a.tb1=b.tb2

where 
 a.IsCurrentRecord=1 )AA)AB
group by sno,date1
)
order by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a window function to detect if a student has been failed in a subject, then set the `Status` to `'Fail'` as the following:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN
                 SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                       OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY StudentId)
                 = 0
            THEN 'Pass' 
            ELSE 'Fail' 
       END Status
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 'Subject1', 'Fail'),
  (1, 'Subject2', 'Pass'),
  (1, 'Subject3', 'Pass'),
  (2, 'Subject1', 'Pass'),
  (2, 'Subject2', 'Pass'),
  (2, 'Subject3', 'Pass'),
  (3, 'Subject1', 'Fail'),
  (3, 'Subject2', 'Fail'),
  (3, 'Subject3', 'Fail')
) T(StudentId, Subject, Result);
```

Comment: this had not provided the expected results

Comment: What does that means @NandkishorGat? Your requirement is when a student fails in 1 or more subject(s), then the status will be FAIL. And that's what the query do.

Comment: (select AB.Number,string_agg(test,',') as Agg,
case when  string_agg(test,',') = 'Authorised' then 'Authorised' 
when string_agg(test,',') in ('Cancelled,Authorised') then 'Authorised' 
when string_agg(test,',') in ('Authorised,Cancelled') then 'Authorised' 
 else 'InProgress' end as status,
date
--resno 
from
(select  distinct number,ResultStatusDescriptionn as test, updateddate as date --,resno
 from

Comment: (select  a.number,a.ResultNumber as resno,ICMSDeterminandDescription,
a.dTimeStamp, a.ReceivedTimeStamp,
--coalesce(dtimestamp,'') as test,
MAX(dTimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY number,statusdescription ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS updateddate,
Modified,
statusdescription,ResultStatusDescription as ResultStatusDescriptionn,TestStatusDescription
from A a 
join B b on
a.tb1=b.tb2
where 
a.Sno in ('14038603','14282440','14282441','14282438','14282446')
 a.IsCurrentRecord=1 )AA)AB
group by Number,date 
)order by 1

Comment: this is the expected output from the query

Comment: SNO result Status Date
14038603 Not entered,Authorised InProgress 8/25/2020 9:46
14038603 Authorised Authorised 8/25/2020 2:10
14282438 Authorised,Not entered InProgress 9/15/2020 19:31
14282440 Authorised,Cancelled Authorised 9/16/2020 19:39
14282441 Authorised Authorised 9/16/2020 19:39
14282446 Authorised Authorised 9/16/2020 19:39

Comment: this is the result which i got it when i use window function

Comment: 14282440 Cancelled Inprogress
14038603 Authorised Inprogress
14282438 Authorised Inprogress
14282438 Not entered Inprogress
14282440 Authorised Inprogress
14282446 Authorised Inprogress
14282441 Authorised Inprogress
14038603 Not entered Inprogress

Comment: trying to explore your query ..i have multiple statuses thats why it is always showing in progress    WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'Not entered' then 'not entered'
   WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'E' THEN 'Entered'
   WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'M' THEN 'Modified'
   WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'X' THEN 'Cancelled'
   WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'A' THEN 'Authorised'
   WHEN RESULT_STATUS = 'R' THEN 'Rejected' ELSE 'Unknown'

Comment: Hi Ilyes,  Anything when we work in the following SUM(CASE WHEN test in ('Authorised','Cancelled')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                       OVER(PARTITION BY samplenumber ORDER BY samplenumber)...we will get correct result